# Chloropleth map with geojson and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geojson

I am trying to map `Human Poverty Index` for [various districts of Nepal](https://github.com/opennepal/odp-poverty/blob/master/Human%20Poverty%20Index%20Value%20by%20Districts%20(2011)/data.csv) with choropleth map in `R` using `geojson` and `ggplot2`.

I read `geojson` data for Nepal with districts [from here](https://github.com/mesaugat/geoJSON-Nepal/blob/master/nepal-districts.geojson).

I saw some examples [here](https://medium.com/@anjesh/step-by-step-choropleth-map-in-r-a-case-of-mapping-nepal-7f62a84078d9), [here](http://prabhasp.github.io/NepalMaps/Poverty/).

This is what I did:

```r
# Read geojson data for nepal with districts
library(tidyverse)
library(geojsonio)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'geojsonio'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     pretty
spdf <- geojson_read("nepal-districts.geojson",  what = "sp")
##https://github.com/mesaugat/geoJSON-Nepal/blob/master/nepal-districts.geojson




#tidy data for ggplot2
library(broom)
spdf_fortified <- tidy(spdf)
#> Regions defined for each Polygons

# plot
ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = spdf_fortified, aes( x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
    theme_void() +
    coord_map()
```

[image]

```r
names(spdf_fortified)
#> [1] "long"  "lat"   "order" "hole"  "piece" "group" "id"



#Now read the data to map to districts
data=read.csv("data.csv")
#data from here
#https://github.com/opennepal/odp-poverty/blob/master/Human%20Poverty%20Index%20Value%20by%20Districts%20(2011)/data.csv

#filter and select data to reflect Value of HPI in various districts
data <- data %>% filter(Sub.Group=="HPI") %>% select(District,Value)


head(data)
#>       District Value
#> 1       Achham 46.68
#> 2 Arghakhanchi 27.37
#> 3        Banke 32.10
#> 4      Baglung 27.33
#> 5      Baitadi 39.58
#> 6      Bajhang 45.32

# Value represents HPI value for each district.

#Now how to merge and fill Value for various districts
#
#
#
#
```

Created on 2018-06-14 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

If I can merge `spdf_fortified` and `data` into `merged_df`, I think I can get the chloropleth map with this code:

```r
ggplot(data = merged_df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + geom_polygon(aes(fill = Value), color = 'gray', size = 0.1)
```

Any help in merging two data ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not to upend your whole system, but I've been working with [sf](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf5.html) a lot lately, and have found it a lot easier to work with than sp. ggplot has good support, too, so you can plot with `geom_sf`, turned into a choropleth by mapping a variable to `fill`:

```r
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

nepal_shp <- read_sf('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mesaugat/geoJSON-Nepal/master/nepal-districts.geojson')
nepal_data <- read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opennepal/odp-poverty/master/Human%20Poverty%20Index%20Value%20by%20Districts%20(2011)/data.csv')

# calculate points at which to plot labels
centroids <- nepal_shp %>% 
    st_centroid() %>% 
    bind_cols(as_data_frame(st_coordinates(.)))    # unpack points to lat/lon columns

nepal_data %>% 
    filter(`Sub Group` == "HPI") %>% 
    mutate(District = toupper(District)) %>% 
    left_join(nepal_shp, ., by = c('DISTRICT' = 'District')) %>% 
    ggplot() + 
    geom_sf(aes(fill = Value)) + 
    geom_text(aes(X, Y, label = DISTRICT), data = centroids, size = 1, color = 'white')
```

[image]

Three of the districts are named differently in the two data frames and will have to be cleaned up, but it's a pretty good starting point without a lot of work.

`ggrepel::geom_text_repel` is a possibility to avoid overlapping labels.

Comment: Clear lucid explanation. Thank you. Is there a way to add labels to districts.

Comment: Sure, with `geom_text` or `geom_label`. They require `x` and `y` aesthetics, though, so you'll need to calculate some beforehand, e.g. with `sf::st_centroid` (whose results you'll still need to unpack). I've edited above to demonstrate.