# Adding names to x,y points on maps using R and geojson data

Tags: r, ggplot2, geojson

I want to easily add names to the districts in Nepal. Most answers online are using a second set of data and joining the map to the data then using that to name points. I do not have data. I just have a geojson with a name column, lat, long, etc.

```
nepal_data <- geojson_read("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mesaugat/geoJSON-Nepal/master/nepal-districts.geojson",  what = "sp")

nepal_fort <- tidy(nepal_data)

nepal_plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = nepal_fort, 
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
               fill="blue", 
               color="white") +
  coord_map()
```

I do not know how to add names to the map. This question is somehow related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50859765/10404767) but without the csv data part.

When I run the code as it is, the plot is generated but I also get:

`Unequal factor levels: coercing to characterbinding character and factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and factor.....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is straightforward when using the `sf`-package

```
library( sf )
library( ggplot2 )
nepal_data <- sf::st_read("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mesaugat/geoJSON-Nepal/master/nepal-districts.geojson")
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf( data = nepal_data, fill = "blue", colour = "white" ) +
  geom_sf_label( data = nepal_data, aes( label = DISTRICT ), size = 2 )
```

[image]